# How to use named routes

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

**Problem**

In Nuxt2, how do I programmatically navigate as a user in Nuxt when routes are nested? I know that I can use `this.$router.push({ name: "exchanges" })` to push a user to the exchanges pages, but when routes are nested, I am not sure what to do. If I use `this.$router.push({ path: "exchanges/create" })` or `this.$router.push("exchanges/create")`, "exchanges/create" gets added to the URL even if I am already at that current URL.

Also, the page component names are "ExchangesPage", "EachExchangePage", "CreateExchangePage", and "HomePage". This didn't work when I tried to use it as the name for the named routes.

**Current File Structure in ./pages**

```
pages/
--| exchanges/
-----| _userId/
--------| index.vue
-----| create/
--------| index.vue
--| index.vue
```

Answer (score 28):

for a quick check about your routes in a nuxt project you can do this:

in your project's directory navigate to this:

```
.nuxt/router.js
```

this is the file with all your routes generated by nuxt and you can check their exact name to navigate to them, look at this picture:

[image]

according to the image above which is from one of my projects I can do this:

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'universities-id' });
```

Comment: What is the equivalent for Nuxt 3 ?

Answer (score 10):

Based on the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing#nested-routes), the names of the nested routes would be:

```
pages/
--| exchanges/
-----| _userId/
--------| index.vue             // name: 'exchanges-userId'
-----| create/
--------| index.vue             // name: 'exchanges-create'
--| index.vue
```

*Example script usage:*

```js
this.$router.push({ name: 'exchanges-userId', params: { userId: 11 } })
this.$router.push({ name: 'exchanges-create' })
```

*Example template usage:*

```html
<nuxt-link :to="{ name: 'exchanges-userId', params: { userId: 11 } }">User 11</nuxt-link>
<nuxt-link :to="{ name: 'exchanges-create' }">Create</nuxt-link>
```

Answer (score 4):

On top of the tips given above, you can also see this in the Vue devtools, in the `Routing > Routes` tab. Everything should be accessible there!

[image]

Comment: note that https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/strategies may be responsible for making it suffixed with locale, e.g. `about-id___en`.