# How to redirect in Nuxt Vue application

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

I have a delete action in Nuxt application. And after a successful delete I need to redirect the user to another page. But in Nuxt [router documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/get-started/routing), there is no mention about redirecting. So the question is how to do it in component?

Comment: What's wrong with `this.$router.push(yourPath)` after successful deletion?

Comment: Dont know. Is it possible? But I would like to use named routes not paths. How to find route name if it is generated by Nuxt?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65366277/how-to-use-named-routes-in-nuxt-js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can totally use either

```html
<nuxt-link :to="{ name: 'my-fancy-route' }">Go to</nuxt-link>
```

or

```js
this.$router.push({ name: 'my-fancy-route' })
```

Depending on what you're trying to achieve here.

Also, all of your routes can be found with the Vue devtools, go to `Routing > Routes` and you will be able to see them all there.

[image]

For more info, Nuxt is using `vue-router` behind the curtains, so a reference to this part of the documentation will be good: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you can use `this.$router.push(yourPath)` to redirect the user. You should be able to use either the route name or explicit path in place of `yourPath`. If you're unsure of the route names generated by Nuxt, you can view them in `.nuxt/routes.json`.

Note that Nuxt uses Vue router so, for more detailed documentation, you might want to [read this](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
this.$router.push({
                path: '/your-path',
            });
```